# Vagrant. Virtual machine with mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, vagrant, chef-infra

Can anyone please provide an example of creating the unix VM with MySQL, that can be accessed from the host machine?

It does not matter whether it via Shell provisioner, Chef or anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples over the internet. As far as installing and configuring MySQL doesn't need many steps, the simplest and fastest way of doing and checking it is using a Bash script for provisioning. 
Using github project [AlexDisler/mysql-vagrant](https://github.com/AlexDisler/mysql-vagrant):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:AlexDisler/mysql-vagrant.git
$ cd mysql-vagrant
$ vagrant up
```

Then you can access MySQL from host using MySQL server ip `33.33.33.1`, user `root` and password `root`

```
$ mysql --host=33.33.33.1 --user=root --password=root
```